# Facebook javascript SDK jQuery request won't get through

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I've been trying to send javascript variables to php using jQuery .post method. The code inside FB.api seems to run as expected when not inside the facebook SDK, inside however it won't run.

```
function testAPI() {

console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');

FB.api(
'/me',
'GET',
{"fields":"id,name,email,gender"}, function(response) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ID=response.id;
        var name=response.name;
        var email=response.email;
        $.post('functions.php', {fuid:ID, ffname:name, femail:email});
    });
});
};
```

And I catch them in functions.php as follows:

```
$fuid=$_POST['fuid'];
$ffname=$_POST['ffname'];
$femail=$_POST['femail'];
```

Comment: What do you mean by "won't run"? Does the callback fire at all?

Comment: Yes people are able to login and the variables are set within Javascript, if this is what you mean.

Comment: Why are you firing jQuery `.ready` function inside FB.api callback? Remove it dude :)

Comment: I removed it and have looked up endless information but the post command just won't go through

Comment: Can you post any errors / information from the developer console?